# Remove time restriction on comment deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

I understand that there is a legitimate purpose to restricting the rate at which comments can be added to a post.

Still users should be *encouraged* to remove comments when they are no longer needed or relevant, and the site should make that as easy and simple as possible.

To that end, I suggest that *removing* one's own comment *not* be subject to the timer restriction.  It is annoying when trying to be good and clean up comments that are no longer relevant to be told that you have to wait 5 seconds to clean up the second one, and it adds no value to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Rate-limiting is necessary to prevent various forms of abuse. 5 seconds between deletions is not a particularly onerous restriction; if you're encountering this *often*, you might want to examine the number of off-topic comments you're posting.

For lengthy, obsolete discussions, you can flag the post and request that the entire conversation be purged - moderators can accomplish this fairly easily without having to remove each comment individually.